# Spring REST caching RSS AbstractRssFeedView

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, rss

I am developing a REST based webservice using springs to serve a RSS feed. Updates to the RSS are very rare (a couple of times a week) and hence I want to cache the RSS feed rather than building it every time someone requests for that. Here is my code. My first request after starting my webserver hits getRssFeed() method in SubscriptionEventHandler class and then goes into SubscriptionRssFeedView and calls buildFeedMetadata, buildFeedItems methods and so on which is correct. But when I make the second request, it skips getRssFeed() method in SubscriptionEventHandler BUT the buildFeedMetadata, buildFeedItems methods in SubscriptionRssFeedView gets called which in turn calls the getIncidents() and builds the RSS again from scratch. Is there a way I can avoid this and cache the RSS until I call the @CacheEvict

Here is my **SubscriptionRssFeedView**

```
@Component("subscriptionRssView")
public class SubscriptionRssFeedView extends AbstractRssFeedView
{

    private String base_Url=”http://mycompany.com/”;

    private final String feed_title = "My RSS Title ";
    private final String feed_desc = "RSS feed desc";
    private final String feed_type = "rss_2.0";

    @Override
    protected void buildFeedMetadata(Map<String, Object> model, Channel feed, HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        feed.setTitle(feed_title);
        feed.setDescription(feed_desc);
        feed.setLink(base_Url);
        feed.setFeedType(feed_type);

        super.buildFeedMetadata(model, feed, request);
    }


    @Override
    protected List<Item> buildFeedItems(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getIncidents()));

        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>(messageList.size());

        for (Message message : messageList)
        {
            itemList.add(createItem(message));
        }

        return itemList;
    }


    private Message[] getIncidents()
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Message[] message = restTemplate.getForObject("http://xxxxx.com/api/message", Message[].class);

        return message;
    }


    private Item createItem(Message message)
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setLink(getFeedItemURL(message));
        item.setTitle(prepareFeedItemTitle(message));
        item.setDescription(createDescription(message));
        item.setPubDate(getLocalizedDateTimeasDate(message.getT()));
        return item;
    }
}
```

My **SubscriptionEventHandler**

```
@Component("SubscriptionService")
public class SubscriptionEventHandler implements SubscriptionService
{

@Autowired
private SubscriptionRssFeedView subscriptionRssFeedView;


@Override
@Cacheable("rssFeedCache")
public SubscriptionRssFeedView getRssFeed()
{
    return subscriptionRssFeedView;
}

}
```

My **SubscriptionService**

```
@Service
public interface SubscriptionService
{
    SubscriptionRssFeedView getRssFeed();
}
```

My **SubscriptionController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/subscription")
public class SubscriptionController
{

@Autowired
private SubscriptionService subscriptionService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/rss", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SubscriptionRssFeedView getRSS() throws Exception
{
    return subscriptionService.getRssFeed();
}
}
```

Comment: check my updated comment

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the response of your SubscriptionController the `render` method of your SubscriptionRssFeedView will always get called. This method is the one triggering the calls to buildFeedMetadata, buildFeedEntries and so and so. The sequence is as follows:

AbstractView.render **=>** AbstractFeedView.renderMergedOutputModel **=>** SubscriptionRssFeedView.buildFeedMetadata and SubscriptionRssFeedView.buildFeedEntries

*you can check the parent classes methods AbstractView.render and AbstractFeedView.renderMergedOutputModel if you want to see in more details what triggers the call to those methods*.

In you want to avoid recalculating the RSS you can cache the `SubscriptionRssFeedView.getIncidents()` method instead of the `SubscriptionEventHandler.getRssFeed()`

I suggest adding a key to your cache otherwise all calls to `getIncidents` will return always the same value and this will be undesired when you have multiple feeds.

Comment: I don't think its the case because when i debug, the getRssFeed() method is called only for the first time and during all subsequent calls the method is not executed. so i am sure it is picking the  subscriptionRssFeedView object from the cache. But rather than serving the previously generated output it rebuilds everything again.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong the about the default key strategy for non-arg methods. I've updated my answer.